# Python reinstallation --enable-unicode=ucs4 and lxml undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_DecodeLatin1

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, installation, libxml2

I'm using Ubuntu Server 14.04.
I needed for my new django project python with ./configure --enable-unicode=ucs4 option. I reinstalled python with ucs4.

Now when I'm trying to run scrapy spider, I get an error like this:

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml-3.4.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/lxml/etree.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_DecodeLatin1
```

Then I'm tried to reinstall python again but got an error:

```
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py ...
make: *** [libinstall] Error 1
```

Then I'm tried to reinstall libxml, but have en error too:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Scrapy reinstallation doesn't help.

Please, help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it.
Maybe it would be useful for someone.
I delete manually with sudo rm -R /usr/local/lib/python2.7 folder with python dist which causes error.
Then I reinstall python, scrapy and django manually from a source.

Comment: Deleting /usr/local/lib/python2.7 did the trick when nothing else worked. Thanks!